# php registration form

Tags: php, database, forms, insert, registration

HI all i am trying to insert some values into database using html form, its giving me the error of ***Column count doesn't match value count at row 1*** which i dont understand, i a new to php plz can anyone help me?
Regards

**php code**

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

      $userName = $_POST["userName"];
      $FirstName =$_POST["FirstName"];
      $LastName =$_POST["LastName"];
  $stnumber = $_Post["ID"];
  $class = $_POST["class"];
  $subject = $_POST["subject"];
  $grade = $_POST["grade"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];

} else{

    echo("wronggggggg nameeeeeeeeeeeee");
}


$stnumber = mysql_escape_string ("ID");
$userName = mysql_escape_string ("userName");
$password = mysql_escape_string ("password");
$FirstName = mysql_escape_string ("FirstName");
$LastName = mysql_escape_string ("LastName");
$class = mysql_escape_string ("class");
$subject = mysql_escape_string ("subject");
$grade = mysql_escape_string ("grade");







mysql_query ("INSERT INTO LOGIN
 VALUES ('$stnumber','$userName','$password','$FirstName','$LastName','$stnumber','$class','$subject','$grade')") or die(mysql_error());





 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE userName ='$userName'");
//$row = mysql_query($sqlUser);
//$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);

if(mysql_num_rows ($sql)> 0){
    echo   ("Upload sucessful");
    } else
{
    echo("Upload fail");

}
```

Comment: Make sure there are absolutely no typos. Compare what you have in your code to your database and make sure everything is correct from the spelling to the capitalization. It's good practice!

Comment: LOGIN has more more or less than 9 columns

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). besides that, `mysql_escape_string` is **always** wrong. you need `mysql_real_escape_string` instead.

Answer (score 2):

**Try This Code**

$insert_qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `LOGIN` (`ID`, `userName`,`password`, `FirstName`,`LastName`,`class`,`subject`,`grade`) VALUES ('".$stnumber."','".$userName."','".$password."','".$FirstName."','".$LastName."','".$class."','".$subject."','".$grade."')") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

Check how many columns are in your table. It should be the exact number as how many you're inserting, i.e., 9 (minus any autoincrement).

Answer (score 0):

You either have to specify the fields that are to be used for the `INSERT`, or correctly insert data to ALL of them.

I suggest that you try editing your query as follows (I have rather assumed the names of your fields):

```
INSERT INTO `LOGIN`
(`stnumber`, `username`, `password`, `forename`, `surname`, `stnumber`, `class`, `subject`, `grade`)
VALUES 
('$stnumber','$userName','$password','$FirstName','$LastName','$stnumber','$class','$subject','$grade')
```

It's worth noting however that you're using a deprecated set of functions. You should investigate the use of [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for better performance and longevity.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO LOGIN
VALUES ('$stnumber','$userName','$password','$FirstName','$LastName','$stnumber','$class','$subject','$grade')") or die(mysql_error());
```

You are using `$stnumber` twice, I don't know if this is intended, but  I'm guessing this probably added an extra value which shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

I find it best to include the column names in the `INSERT` statement to explicitly define which values are being inserted into which column.  For example:

```
INSERT INTO `table` ( `column_1`, `column_2` )
VALUES ( 'value_1', 'value_2' );
```

You may also consider reviewing [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as it is a much safer alternative to `mysql_query` calls, which as of v5.5.0, will be deprecated.

If you provide your table structure, we may be able to identify exactly which columns are missing/extra from your INSERT statement.